# uninstall, remove or disable cloud-init on centos

Tags: centos, cloud-init

I installed cloud-init on centos 6.4 using command yum install cloud-init.
But now I want to completely get rid of it, or if it is impossible to at least disable. I looked through internet but failed to find any solution.

Could you suggest how the installed cloud-init could be eliminated from centos?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The way to disable it is:

```
sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

And/or set `cloud-init=disabled` on the kernel command line if it's enabled at boot time. See the [cloud-init docs](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/boot.html) for details on the boot stages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> yum remove cloud-init

But it will remove only cloud-init, all installed dependencies will stay on your system.

Comment: Thanks, it proved to be more complicated. Recommended on AWS, cloud-init in fact ruins an already working linux machine i.e. it changes user ssh keys and sshd settings. uninstalling with yum it does not revert the ruined settings. so they have to be reset manually to enable users to logon.